# How to read inbox mails from Microsoft Outlook using python macOS?

Tags: python, outlook, py-appscript

I want to verify whether I am receiving an email from a "sender" with a "subject" and a particular "email" template. I have seen help links with win32 module that works for windows. I want to know the way to read the mails from my Microsoft Outlook from macOS.

Answer (score -2):

I had something similar using **appscript** library. You would need to have it installed.

```
pip install appscript
```

The sample code is something like this, you may to need to extend it for your use case.

```
from appscript import app, k

def make_msg(text):
    outlook = app('Microsoft Outlook')

    msg = outlook.make(
        new=k.outgoing_message,
        with_properties={
            k.subject: 'Test Email',
            k.plain_text_content: text})

    msg.make(
        new=k.recipient,
        with_properties={
            k.email_address: {
                k.name: '<My name>',
                k.address: '<My email ID>'}})
    msg.open()
    msg.activate()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    make_msg("Sample text")
```

Let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: The question was about reading emails already received, but your answer is about sending new emails.